# Why the input tag is going in next line?I want it in the same line

Tags: html

```
<p>Name:</p><input type="text" style="display: inline" >
```

The input tag is going in the next line.I want it to be in the same line.I used the css styling property too but it isn't helping.

Comment: Post your code that you tried so far ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `p` element is a block element.  If you want anything to be inline with it, then it too would need to be inline:

```
<p style="display:inline">Name:</p><input type="text" />
```

Comment: Or he can change the `p` tag for a `span` tag.

Comment: @IgorUnger: There are lots of ways to achieve what the OP is looking for.  I'm simply explaining *why* he's seeing the behavior he's seeing, so he can better understand how styling is applied to the elements he's using.  Yes, as other comments and answers point out, changing the markup would affect how that markup is rendered.  But it wouldn't answer the question of *why*.

Comment: You're right when saying that <p> is an block element.

Answer (score 0):

As @David explained the `<p>` tag is a block element. That means in won't align inline on default.

To solve your problem change your markup to:

```
<p>Name: <input [...] /></p>
```

But for what you are trying to do there is the label-tag.

```
<label for="name">Name: </label><input type="text" name="name" />
```